# Do I need Bind Pose Bone Transformation for my mesh Animation?

Tags: c++, opengl, animation, graphics

1. I have a Hand mesh which I want to animate.
2. I have the Skeleton which can be hierarchically animated.
3. My mesh is also weighted in Blender. So each vertex has 4 associated bones to be affected by.
4. When I apply the Animation of my Skeleton to the mesh, the hierarchy is applied correctly. (so the hierarchy of the mesh, matches the hierarchy of the Skeleton).

So far so good, now question:
the fingers look to be stretched (its like the fingers smashed by a heavy door). Why?

Note: (I didnt apply the bind pose bone Transformation Matrix explicitly, but I read about it and I believe its functionality is there, in the hierarchical Transformation I have for my Skeleton).

If you need more clarification of the steps, please ask.

```
vector<glm::mat4> Posture1Hand::HierarchyApplied(HandSkltn HNDSKs){

    vector <glm::mat4> Matrices; 
Matrices.resize(HNDSKs.GetLimbNum());

    //non Hierarchical Matrices
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Matrices.size(); i++){
        Matrices[i] = newPose[i].getModelMatSkltn(HNDSKs.GetLimb(i).getLwCenter());
    }


    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Matrices.size(); i++){
        vector<Limb*>childeren = HNDSKs.GetLimb(i).getChildren();
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < childeren.size(); j++){
            Matrices[childeren[j]->getId()] = Matrices[i] * Matrices[childeren[j]->getId()];
        }
    }
    return Matrices;
}
```

Here is my getModelMatSkltn method.

```
inline glm::mat4 getModelMatSkltn(const glm::vec3& RotationCentre) const{//to apply the rotation on the whole heirarchy
    glm::mat4 posMatrix = { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
    posMatrix = glm::translate(posMatrix, newPos);

    glm::mat4 trMatrix = { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
    glm::mat4 OriginTranslate = glm::translate(trMatrix, -RotationCentre);
    glm::mat4 InverseTranslate = glm::translate(trMatrix, RotationCentre);


    glm::mat4 rotXMatrix = { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
    rotXMatrix = glm::rotate(rotXMatrix, glm::radians(newRot.x), glm::vec3(1, 0, 0));

    glm::mat4 rotYMatrix = { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
    rotYMatrix = glm::rotate(rotYMatrix, glm::radians(newRot.y), glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));

    glm::mat4 rotZMatrix = { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
    rotZMatrix = glm::rotate(rotZMatrix, glm::radians(newRot.z), glm::vec3(0, 0, 1));

    glm::mat4 scaleMatric = { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
    scaleMatric = glm::scale(scaleMatric, newScale);

    glm::mat4 rotMatrix = rotZMatrix*rotYMatrix*rotXMatrix;

    rotMatrix = InverseTranslate*rotMatrix*OriginTranslate;

    return posMatrix*rotMatrix*scaleMatric;
}
```

and this is how I send 20 transformation Matrix (because of 20 joints in Hand) to GPU:

void GLShader::Update(const vector trMat, const GLCamera& camera){

```
vector<glm::mat4> MVP; MVP.resize(trMat.size());
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < trMat.size(); i++){
    MVP[i] = camera.getViewProjection()* trMat[i];
}
glUniformMatrix4fv(newUniform[TRANSFORM_U], trMat.size(), GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0][0]);//4 floating value
```

}

I guess one should be familiar with calculation of vertex position in the shader in order to be able to answer the question, but I send a part of my vertex shader too.

```
attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec2 texCoord;
attribute vec4 weight;
attribute vec4 weightInd;


uniform mat4 transform[20];//vector of uniform for 20 number of joints in my skleton

void main(){
    mat4 WMat;//weighted matrix
    float w;
    int Index;
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++){
        Index=int(weightInd[i]);
        w=weight[i];
            WMat += w*transform[Index];
    }
    gl_Position= WMat*vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: I do not have a problem with blender. When I calculate my vertices position in the shader, for some reason it goes wrong. I believe I am missing something in my code. Maybe this transformation matrix, or something else. So my issue is exactly a programming issue. Maybe you are not that familiar with OpenGl, skinning in C++, and using FBX files.

Comment: Fair enough, then since your question is about programming I would advise you post your current code, otherwise we have nothing to work on.

Comment: hmm, that is fine! I like to clarify my code and I like to share my code. But which part? my code is a bit big by now, to fit here :). To be honest I do not know which part is having the problem too. is it because of shader, is it because my Mesh data structure, is it because of my matrix calculation, and its hierarchy, .... But ok I will share the calculation of my hierarchy, in just a moment

Comment: how do you send the code normally? it seems very messy :D

Comment: Normally you would click on the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34356771/edit) link and add that code to your question itself.

Comment: here we go. Looks much better.